# TableLayoutのTableRowの要素が右にはみ出る？

Tags: android, java, xml

TableLayoutを使ったレイアウトを作成中です。
TableRowに`android:paddingStart`を設定すると、一番右側に配置した要素(ImageButton)がはみ出してしまい、期待したレイアウトになりません。
はみ出さないようにするにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？コード側でも何か記述が必要でしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:shrinkColumns="0,2"
             android:stretchColumns="1"
             android:background="#cccccc">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
              android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
              android:layout_marginBottom="0.2dp"
              android:background="#ffffff">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl"
                  android:labelFor="@+id/txtTel"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/LBL_950_TEL"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtTel"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:inputType="phone"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnTel"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@mipmap/ic_call_black"
                     android:contentDescription="@string/tel"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: 動かして確認してはいませんが、`TableRow`の`android:layout_width`が`match_parent`で指定されていて、さらにその親にあたる`TableLayout`の`android:layout_width`は`wrap_content `で指定されています。なので横幅は内包されている`TextView`と`EditText`と`ImageButton`の幅を合わせた長さとなるために横幅が画面からはみ出しているのだと思います。

Comment: Tabl‌​eLayoutの方も`match_parent`にしてみましたが、状況変わらずです＞＜

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の点を修正することではみ出さないようなレイアウトにできました。
・`TableLayout`の`layout_width`を`match_parent`に修正
・`TableLayout`の`shrinkColumns`と`stretchColumns`を削除
・`EditText`に`layout_weight`の指定を追加

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#cccccc">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.2dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtTel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LBL_950_TEL"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtTel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_call_black"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tel"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

推測ですが、はみ出していた原因は横幅の伸縮が`TableLayout`の`shrinkColumns`と`stretchColumns`によって計算されていたためではないでしょうか。
paddingによる`TableRow`の左右の領域が計算されずに`TextView`、`EditText`、`ImageButton`をぞれぞれ伸縮するため、左右paddingの分がはみ出していたのかと思います。

試してはいませんが、`TableRow`にpaddingを指定するのではなく、padding用のviewを`TextView`の前と`ImageButton`の後ろに配置することで、`shrinkColumns`と`stretchColumns`による伸縮ではみ出さないようにレイアウトできるかもしれません。

---

追記
`layout_weight`を使用せずに、padding用のviewと`shrinkColumns`と`stretchColumns`を使ってレイアウトしました。

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="0,1,3,4"
    android:stretchColumns="2"
    android:background="#cccccc">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.2dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/row_padding_start"
            android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl"
            android:labelFor="@+id/txtTel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LBL_950_TEL"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtTel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="phone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_call_black"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tel"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/row_padding_end"
            android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: layout_weightを使った方法で思い通りのレイアウトにすることができました！padding用のviewを入れる方法も、複雑なレイアウトを扱う際に使わせて頂きたいと思います。助かりました<(_ _)>

Answer (score 0):

android4.0ではGridlayoutがサポートされましたので、そちらを使う方がレイアウトの自由度
が上がり、問題も起きにくいですよ。